# SQL Server BULK IMPORT numeric (byte) value stored in text field

Tags: sql-server, database, informix

I am trying to migrate the data from a very old Informix DB to SQL Server. I am using UNLOAD on the Informix side to dump the data into text files. I then use BULK IMPORT on the SQL Server side to load the files.

The person who designed this DB is using a CHAR(6) field to store numeric data on Informix. You can see the example in the update_flag column field 6 (54-). If you look at the field in Notepad++ it looks like "54[SOH][SOH][SOH][EM]"

```
 99|8880327|056-41|802|STTB|54-| |0.0|0.0|10.0|10.0|10.0|10.0|30.0|20.0|50.0    
 98|8880327|056-41|802|ST|&| |0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|10.0
```

When I try to import this into SQL Server, I get an error:

> Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character
> for the specified codepage) for row 301, column 6 (update_flag).

Is there a way to convert this 6-byte field into its numeric value during the bulk import? For example, the first 2 bytes in the first record "54" (byte value 0011 0110 0011 0101) would convert to decimal 13,877

Please keep in mind that this version of Informix is from 1990 so a lot of things like CAST() are not available.

Comment: Is it fair to assume this is an SE database rather than an OnLine database?  An SE database uses a directory with a name that ends `.dbs` (e.g. `stores.dbs` for database `stores`) that contains pairs of files that end `.dat` (data) and `.idx` (index).  I have ways to deal with exporting data from such databases when there are problems.  Do you know the encoding used for the 'number stored in CHAR(6) column'?

Comment: Yes. This is a version 4.10 Informix DB running on AIX (3.2) on an RS6000 server. As far as I know there is not a specific encoding for the char(6) column. The original programmer did some bitwise shifting to pack values into the 6 bytes. It is actually 2 values. One occupies the first 2 bytes of the field and the other occupies the last 4 bytes.

Comment: Can you still get hold of the code used to encode and decode that field?  If so, I have tools that can probably help.  However, it is probably better discussed via email — see my profile.  Please clearly reference this question in the email.